# A PHP script used on my home server to download YouTube videos

Tags: php, linux, shell, server, raspberry-pi

I have a PHP page I used to download YouTube videos, hosted on my Pi 4.

The site is only going to be used on my home network (so a dot local address), but it allows me to download videos on my phone or computer without downloading any executables or special apps.

The user can submit a request on an HTML page with four options:

```
Form ID      : Description to user
----------------------------------------
bestquality  : MP4 (video with sound)
worstquality : MP4 (video without sound)
bestaudio    : M4A
worstaudio   : WEBM
```

This is a majority of the code used to make this:

```
<?php

//the file extension
$formatExt = "";

switch($_GET['format']) {
    case 'bestvideo': case 'worstvideo': $formatExt = "MP4"; break;
    case 'bestaudio': $formatExt = "m4a"; break;
    case 'worstaudio': $formatExt = "webm";
        break;
    default:
        echo("Illegal video format '".$_GET['format']."'!");
        exit(1);
}

$url = $_GET['url'];
$format = $_GET['format'];
$ytcmd = 'youtube-dl';

$directoriesInUse = array_filter(glob("./workers/*"), 'is_dir');

$integerIDs = array(sizeof($directoriesInUse));


//if the working directory changes, make sure to change the 2 at the end of the
//expression in the for loop to match the amount of '/' characters.
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($directoriesInUse); $i++)
    $integerIDs[$i] = (int)explode("/", $directoriesInUse[$i])[2];

//If these are not sorted, it will see a list of 1 thru 14 and pick 9 as the largest number (because that's how the directory would be listed)
sort($integerIDs);

$numberToUse = $integerIDs[sizeof($integerIDs) - 1] + 1;

//prevent exploiting and issuing server commands
$url = str_replace(" ", "", $url);
$url = str_replace("|", "", $url);

//url may contain & for a playlist, so it will be removed here to prevent other issues.
$url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "&"));

//Download the video, the "--format" option will not download audio for a video (worstvideo is video w/o audio)
if($format === "bestaudio" or $format === "worstaudio" or $format === "worstvideo")
        $response = exec('mkdir ./workers/'.$numberToUse.' && cd ./workers/'.$numberToUse.'/ && '.$ytcmd.' --no-playlist --format '.$format.' -o \'%(title)s.%(ext)s\' '.$url);
else
        $response = exec('mkdir ./workers/'.$numberToUse.' && cd ./workers/'.$numberToUse.'/ && '.$ytcmd.' --no-playlist -o \'%(title)s.%(ext)s\' '.$url);

//Get the first file in a directory, this SHOULD be the video that was downloaded.  It is not possible (AFAIK) to get the file name of a video from the youtube-dl binary
function magicWorkers($path) {
    return array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'))[2];
}

//change file date so the crontab doesn't delete the file too early (youtube-dl may save the file with the date it was uploaded)
echo exec("touch ./workers/".$numberToUse."/".magicWorkers("./workers/".$numberToUse));

//sleep 2 seconds for good measure (in case things haven't updated for whatever reason, this has happened!)
sleep(2);

//This works, but I would like to find an alternative soon (prompt download vs direct)
header("Location: ./workers/".$numberToUse.'/'.magicWorkers("./workers/".$numberToUse));

exit(0);
```

The server is being hosted on an Apache2 web server in the `/var/www/html/` directory, and Apache2 has rw- access in the `/var/www/html/workers/` directory. It is running running PHP 7.2.24.

I have seen some security problems with this before, for instance, inputting `example.com/video && cowsay MOO` will execute the cowsay command, so I made a small patch by disabling the characters " " (space), "&", and "|".

My other concern is that I am linking the user directly to the file to download, whereas it would be better (and probably more secure) if they were prompted for the download.

One last thing: I have a crontab that runs every minute to delete files in the `workers` directory (older than two hours) to make sure that the space on the Pi doesn't fill up (directories do not get deleted).

Comment: Rather than removing specific characters you should use [escapeshellarg](https://php.net/escapeshellarg) to escape it ensuring that any special characters are handled appropriately, otherwise someone could still pass through unclosed quotes causing you errors or even run their own commands with `$(command-here)`.

Comment: Which version of PHP is it running? I tried running it locally and see a *syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER)* due to the  `exit 0;` I tried it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ with various versions of 4,5 and 7 and all of them show that syntax error...

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ it was that the exit command did not have parentheses.  It ran fine on my machine when I tested for syntax errors.  I have updated the question by the way.  EDIT: I am running PHP 7.2.24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Initial thoughts

I must admit I hadn't heard of the [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html) program but it seems quite nifty. Perhaps it was what many of the websites I have seen for downloading YT videos use behind the scenes.

I tried using the script locally and found that the URL **must contain an ampersand** (i.e. have 2+ query string variables), otherwise the logic to look for a playlist parameter and remove it would lead to an empty string passed to the youtube-dl program. But some URLs I see from Youtube only have zero or one parameters (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuB6UjEsY_Y and the equivalent sharing link: https://youtu.be/DuB6UjEsY_Y).

Initially I was wondering why `$numberToUse` couldn't be set to `count($directoriesInUse) + 1` but then I realized that some of those directories could be deleted and that might lead to issues. Then I considered that if you could parse out a video id (which [seems to have remained the same since 2014](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/54448))  from the URL then that could be used instead of an integer for the sub-directory name.

## Suggestions

### Use a mapping instead of a `switch`

The `switch` could be simplified:

> ```
> switch($_GET['format']) {
>     case 'bestvideo': case 'worstvideo': $formatExt = "MP4"; break;
>     case 'bestaudio': $formatExt = "m4a"; break;
>     case 'worstaudio': $formatExt = "webm";
>         break;
>     default:
>         echo("Illegal video format '".$_GET['format']."'!");
>         exit(1);
> }
> ```

A mapping could be defined of formats to extensions:

```
const FORMAT_MAPPING = [
    'bestvideo' => "MP4",
    'worstvideo' => "MP4",
    'bestaudio' => "m4a",
    'worstaudio' => "webm"
];
```

Then if the query string is missing that key or that key does not exist in the mapping, show the error and exit early.

```
if (!isset($_GET['format']) || !array_key_exists($_GET['format'], FORMAT_MAPPING)) {
    echo("Illegal video format '".$_GET['format']."'!");
    exit(1);
}
```

Otherwise just assign the value to `$formatExt`:

```
$formatExt = FORMAT_MAPPING[$_GET['format']];
```

### Control structures not using statement groups

While it may seem unlikely that there would be a need for multiple lines following `if`, `else` or `for` statements, it is best to put the statements to execute in a group (i.e. with curly braces/brackets). Then when you determine that you need to add a line to one of those statement groups, it eliminates any chance of logic error.

> ```
> if($format === "bestaudio" or $format === "worstaudio" or $format === "worstvideo") {
>         $response = exec('mkdir ./workers/'.$numberToUse.' && cd ./workers/'.$numberToUse.'/ && '.$ytcmd.' --no-playlist --format '.$format.' -o \'%(title)s.%(ext)s\' '.$url);
> }
> else {
>         $response = exec('mkdir ./workers/'.$numberToUse.' && cd ./workers/'.$numberToUse.'/ && '.$ytcmd.' --no-playlist -o \'%(title)s.%(ext)s\' '.$url);
> }
> ```

### `or` has lower precedence than `||` and others like assignment

Note the [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) list and how `or` is at the end of the list, while logical or i.e. `||`, is above assignment and others:

[image: operator precedence]

[image: operator precedence end]

There is a [good illustration of the difference in the user contributed notes by fabmlk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php#117390):

> Watch out for the difference of priority between 'and vs &&' or '|| vs or':
>
> ```
> <?php
> $bool = true && false;
> var_dump($bool); // false, that's expected
>
> $bool = true and false;
> var_dump($bool); // true, ouch!
> ?>
> ```
>
> Because 'and/or' have lower priority than '=' but '||/&&' have higher.

So it is wise to get in the practice of using `||` unless you know you need `or`

### use `foreach` instead of `for`

Instead of this `for` loop:

> ```
> for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($directoriesInUse); $i++)
>     $integerIDs[$i] = (int)explode("/", $directoriesInUse[$i])[2];
> ```

A [`foreach`](https://php.net/foreach) could be used

```
foreach ($directoriesInUse as $i => $directory) {
    $integerIDs[$i] = (int)explode("/", $directory)[2];
}
```

One could also use `array_map()`. Instead of storing an array of integers, you could just keep track of the maximum number seen - using [`max()`](https://www.php.net/max). That would avoid the need to sort the array. This likely wouldn’t be a major optimization unless there were a large number of directories.

### Logical flaw when no ampersand exists in URL

As was mentioned above, this line doesn't work well when there is no ampersand in `$url`

> ```
> //url may contain & for a playlist, so it will be removed here to prevent other issues.
> $url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "&"));
> ```

This is because [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) "Returns **`FALSE`** if the needle was not found."<sup>[1](http://php.net/strpos)</sup>. I would update the code to only perform that alteration if the string actually contains an ampersand.

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://php.net/strpos</sub>

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I’ve stated in my question that I did not want an ampersand because I did not want to allow playlists to be downloaded.  The only other character besides an ampersand would be `?`, used in `youtube.com/watch?v=...`, which isn’t deleted.  Also, I added an ampersand at the end of the URL, though it isn’t in this question, to prevent issues; however, I did not even consider that `strpos()` would return *false* if it was provided no ampersand, which explains why there were issues.  Thank you again for answering.

Answer (score 4):

## Security

### Command injection

> I made a small patch by disabling the characters " " (space), "&", and "|".

This can easily be bypassed. Example:

```
url=http://example.com/;id;?%26x=y;
```

Other relevant characters include - but are not limited to - `$`, ```, etc.

As mentioned in the comments, you should use `escapeshellarg` instead (input filtering is quite difficult).

### XSS

This is vulnerable to XSS:

```
echo("Illegal video format '".$_GET['format']."'!");
```

An attacker can exploit this to run arbitrary JavaScript on the domain the script is hosted on. If there are other applications hosted there, this might have a significant impact. XSS also allows bypass of CSRF protection (see next point).

You should apply `htmlentities` to any user-supplied value you output.

### CSRF / Missing authentication

As-is, anyone could get you to download a video by including an `img` tag to the PHP script in a website, an email, etc.

This also allows remote attackers who are not in your home network to execute arbitrary code on your computer via the command injection issue.

I would suggest to add *some* form of authentication here, and if it's only a hardcoded key you pass in the URL.